# Fellowships of smaller amount to support your main postdoctoral fellowship

Tags: application, postdocs, funding

I've a certain postdoctoral scholarship for a year in certain area of applied science. But the scholarship is not very generous compared to the local cost of living (think of Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowship as something very generous for any place), so I'm planning to apply for a scholarship which I'm okay with being relatively smaller amount (as much as € 500/month or $ 700/month is good enough, more is of course better :), which I can earn as my 'research expenses' scholarship, or some such similar.

Do you know of any such examples of such a scholarship? If yes, could you please be kind enough to mention them?

Comment: Careful with this: either or both of the funding agencies may have "double dipping" restrictions that forbid you from accepting other scholarships.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I think the distinction is usually made between fellowships and other scholarships and awards. Double-dipping would be accepting another fellowship, but smaller scale awards (such as supplements awarded by universities with higher stipends, for instance) are normally allowed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "shopping question" and also unanswerable without more information about country and research field.

Answer (score 2):

Two obvious possibilities come to mind:

- travel grants (there is plenty of variations, including e.g. small travel grants provided by the grant agencies and grants for attending a particular conference given by the conference organizers)
- intramural grants (this is strongly institution-dependent, of course).